# How to make wall posts made by users on app's facebook page

Tags: facebook, facebook-wall

Is there anything I need to do to make posts users make on their wall via a custom ios application using it's own facebook app id, also appear on app's  (facebook app it uses I mean) own facebook page?

I would expect this to appear automatically but it doesn't seem to be the case.

Answer (score 1):

In order to read one's Facebook wall, you need the `access token` to authenticate reading. This will give you access to all non-public wall posts. From this, you can pass the newly posted content to your page through the `feed` action.

**Reference**: http://php-academy.blogspot.com/2011/04/how-to-post-from-facebook-app-to.html

Enjoy and good luck!

Comment: FYI, I am not talking about wall posts done by other apps, only the ones done from my app. So you are saying that I need to do something manually everytime someone do a wall post from my app for it to also appear on my facebook app's page?